# jquery .animation() height direction

Tags: jquery

i have a problem to set `.animate()` of height from, top to bottom, of chat divs.
I have `.userChatWrapper` with  `position:fixed` and `bottom:0` (so individually chats are force to stay inside of viewport) and inside of it, `.userChat` div. On `#minimize` it should replicate behavior of Google chat (slide down to 40px (height of header), delay, and then slide down to 4px). It works with `.userChat` set to `position:absolute` as shown here [JSFiddle-absolut](http://jsfiddle.net/aleksacavic/syj6LfqL/2/), but with `position:relative` is scrolls up, and get messy, as shown here [JSFiddle-relative](http://jsfiddle.net/aleksacavic/ghr7x768/1/).
Relative positioning is handy because i can `float:right` `.userChat` divs so as conversations are initiated they appears next to each others.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal flow of the content/height is to grow from top to bottom and reducing the height will reduce it to the opposite direction to that flow. `position:absolute` allows you to move the weight of the div at the bottom (with `bottom:0`) and in effect change the direction of growth and thatswhy it looks nice in your first fiddle example.

In your second example I suggest animating `bottom:-x` instead of the height.. something like this

```
yourdiv.animate({bottom:'-390px'},"slow").delay(500).animate({bottom:'-410px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.slideToggle()` and the other slide animations.
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp

Comment: Why not link to jQuery docs instead of 3rd party? Official docs stay more often up to date and relevant.

Comment: thanks for comments
@Jaak thanks for commenting. yes you have a point there . Do you think it could be a (part of) problem?
@ Sterling, as I'm aware (correct me if I'm wrong) it offers less comfort, it doesn't take any params as animate do? Beside, i have general wondering am i doing something really wrong here, for further similar situations...

Comment: @somename .slideToggle just uses .animate under the hood, wouldn't make the difference ^^